# In Java 8 parallel Streams, do terminal operations finish all computation before returning?

Tags: java, java-8

For example, if class `Foo` has instance method `bar()`,

```
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
list.stream()
    .parallel()
    .forEach(Foo::bar);
doSomething();
```

Is it guaranteed that all calls to `bar()` have returned before `doSomething()` is called?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, except for when the terminal operation is either `iterator()` or `spliterator()`.

From the [java.util.stream package page:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

> In almost all cases, terminal operations are eager, completing their traversal of the data source and processing of the pipeline before returning. Only the terminal operations iterator() and spliterator() are not; these are provided as an "escape hatch" to enable arbitrary client-controlled pipeline traversals in the event that the existing operations are not sufficient to the task.

Comment: But beware that this does not hold when the operation does not complete normally. In the case of an exception there might be concurrent operations still running at the time you catch it.